# Can I create a zombie process using powershell? (I know this sounds bad, but I'm need to test another script)

Tags: powershell, zombie-process

I know this is a pretty bad idea; but I have a script that checks for zombie processes, and I want to test it. Currently it looks at two separate processes across different machines. If their parent process ID doesn't exist, it echos the Hostname and PID. I think it is working correctly; but I always like to confirm my scripts with tests. Is there any way i could confirm that it is working correctly? I would want to create a zombie process; but I don't know if that would be the best way (also I don't know how I could easily create one in a controlled manner). Here is the script I wrote:

```
$m = "System1 System2 System3"
$zombies

foreach($a in $m.split(" "))
{
    $pros = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_Process -Namespace root/cimv2 -ComputerName $a
    $pids = @()

    foreach($pro in $pros)
    {
        $pids += $pro.ProcessId
    }

    foreach($pro in $($pros | Where-Object {$_.Name -eq "Proc1.exe" -or $_.Name -eq "Proc2.exe"}))
    {
        if($pids -notcontains $pro.ParentProcessId)
        {
            $zombies += "HOST: $(pro.MachineName) PID: $($pro.ProcessId)"
        }
    }
}

foreach($zombie in $zombies)
{
    Write-Output $zombie
}
```

Comment: I know you said it was a bad idea, but any programmer worth his/her salt should make it a high priority not to create zombie processes.

Comment: What is the meaning of zombi process on Wondows Systems ? A process without parent process has no special meaning on Windows. The process filiation is not so strong as in Linux. As far as I understand on Windows a defunct process does not stay in the process table.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the following command :

cmd /c Notepad.exe

You get the following result :

[image]

If you kill cmd.exe you will get :

[image]

The parent is still cmd.exe PID 8960 that just not exist. Ans as far as I understand another process can be created with PID 8960.